# ItemsControl contents overflow the grid row before getting clipped

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a page with a two row grid. In the first row I have a databound ItemsControl and in the second row a simple textbox.

The problem is that while the page is loading (i.e. it is animated into the view), the ItemScontrol's content overflows over the entire grid. Only after the page is fully shown after a short while (it seems exactly 1 second, although I haven't measured it), the contents get properly clipped to the Grid row.

Here's what happens while loading the page (not that there are some transitions on this screenshot however they do not have an effect on this behavior):

[image]

After the page is fully loaded, contents get clipped properly:

[image]

Here's the pseudo-XAML:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <!-- grid for each row -->
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I figured out that clipping works properly if I set the ItemsControl's (but not the StackPanel's!) height to a fixed value, however of course I don't want the height to be fixed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are the ItemsControl and TextBox surrounded by a StackPanel?

Comment: There are some additional controls there (that don't really affect this behavior)